# AnonymousID always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the AnonymousID in asp.net C# to be set when a user is not logged-in; in my Global.asax.cs file, I've added this class to set it:

```
protected void AnonymousIdentification_Creating(object sender, AnonymousIdentificationEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AnonymousID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

Then on my CurrentUser class, I did this:

```
userId = HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID;
```

However the AnonymousID is **always** null, it never gets set.

Note: a previous question on a similar issue was asked, but an actual resolution never posted:

[AnonymousId is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286498/anonymousid-is-always-null)

Comment: found a page saying that clearing the cookies resolved the issue.

Comment: You're right! That worked perfectly; locals now displays the AnonymousID. If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the cookies and it will start working.

Comment: I logged out , and this started working.